# cumulative distinct count in hive

Tags: count, hive, distinct, cumulative-sum

Here is some sample data from table `daily_user`. Each row represents an active user on a specific day, the revenue is based on the money generated by the user on that day. The earliest date in this table is 1/1.

```
date user_id group revenue  
1/1  1       a     1  
1/1  2       b     0  
1/1  3       a     0  
1/2  2       b     10  
1/2  3       a     0  
1/3  3       a     1
```

The output I want (Basically, each row tells me for each group, from 1/1 to each observation date, how many users have ever paid. For example, the last row means from 1/1-1/3, for group b, in total we have 1 user who paid us):

```
end_date    group     # users who ever paid  
1/1          a             1  
1/1          b             0   
1/2          a             1  
1/2          b             1  
1/3          a             2  
1/3          b             1
```

There seems to be some UDFs to do cumulative sum, but I am not sure if there is any cumulative distinct count function that I can leverage here. Is there anyway to struct a hive query to implement this?

Comment: Do you mean cumulative *distinct* count or cumulative discount count?

Comment: I meant distinct, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is to actually 'collect_set' the users ( collect unique values) and take the size of the array, for small numbers of user ( ie. which would fit in memory)

```
SELECT size( collect_set( user_id ) ) as uniques
       end_date, group
FROM daily_user
GROUP BY end_date, group;
```

For large numbers of uniques, you'll need a probabilistic data structure, like sketch sets or hyperloglogs,  available as UDF's from the Brickhouse library ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ).   This will give you an estimate which is close, but not the exact number of uniques

```
SELECT estimated_reach( sketch_set( user_id )) as uniques_est,
       end_date, group
FROM daily_user
GROUP BY end_date, group;
```

You can also merge these, so that can merge pre-calculated collections/sketches from previous days.  Something like :

```
SELECT size(combine_unique( unique_set ) ) as uniques,
      group
FROM daily_uniques
WHERE end_date > date_add( today, -30 )
GROUP BY group;
```

or

```
SELECT estimated_reach( union_sketch( unique_sketch) ) as uniques,
       group
FROM daily_uniques
WHERE end_date > date_add( today, -30 )
GROUP BY group;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `if(revenue=0,1,0)` will have value 1 if the revenue is 0, and will have value 0 otherwise. Summing this function will give you the total number of people who had revenue of 0:

```
select
  date as end_date,
  group,
  sum(if(revenue=0,1,0)) as number_of_users_who_never_paid
from
  daily_user
group by
  date,
  group
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I am actually more interested in getting the cumulative payer count.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this, without writing a custom UDF, would be to do some sort of cartesian join:

```
select
  date as end_date,
  group,
  sum(if(mon.user_id is not null AND mon.date <= du.date,1,0)) as cumulative_spenders
from
  daily_user du
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
   select
     distinct
     user_id,
     date,
     group
   from
     daily_user 
   where
     revenue > 0
   ) mon
ON
  (du.user_id=mon.user_id and du.group=mon.group)
group by
  date,
  group
```

This will generate a row per spending transaction per entry in the original table, then aggregate from there.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, is cumulative_spenders unique for each user?  It seems user_id 1 will still have multiple rows in the query result

Comment: Yes, that is true - added a distinct which should fix the issue